# How should I convert a Python tuple of strings into dynamically-specified types?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm writing a simple Python application using the `cmd` module to provide a CLI-type interface. The commands provided by my CLI have parameter lists that vary widely. Each command handler receives a string argument containing the portion of the line that contains arguments; I plan to tokenize them into a tuple using `shlex.split`. Subsequently, I'm looking for the most Pythonic way to take that tuple of strings, validate that they are well-formed, and convert them into a tuple of cleanly-specified numeric types.

**Example:** I have a function `foo` that takes 3 arguments: the first is a path to a file on disk, the second is a floating-point value, and the third is an integer, like:

```
foo /home/jason/file.bin 123.456 123456
```

I'd like a clean way of specifying this, something akin to using C's `sscanf()` with a format string of `"%s %f %d"` (I understand the whitespace-handling issues inherent in that approach; it's just an illustration).

I know that I can accomplish this by writing boilerplate code for each handler function that calls `int()`, `float()`, etc. and catches exceptions appropriately. It just seems that there should be a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest providing the production rules as functions that parse the arguments, and raise an exception for invalid arguments.  so. your example might look like this:

```
FOO_SYNTAX = (file, float, int)
def foo_cmd(infile, infloat, inint):
    pass

def parse_args(rule, args):
    if len(rule) != len(args):
        raise ValueError, "Wrong number of arguments"
    return [rule_item(arg) for rule_item, arg in zip(rule, args)]

COMMANDS = {'foo': (FOO_SYNTAX, foo_cmd)}

def dispatch(line):
    cmd, rest = line.split(None, 1)
    args = rest.split()
    syntax, cmd_func = COMMANDS[cmd]
    cmd_func(*parse_args(syntax, args))
```

Comment: That's exactly the type of approach I was looking for; I think it's a great solution.

Comment: One comment: maybe I misinterpreted your intent, but in the last line of `parse_args`, I assumed the `RULE` was meant to be lower-case, iterating through the `rule` list and applying each conversion function to the corresponding element-wise string in the `args` list. It seems that `map()` only takes a single function for its first argument, so instead, I used a list comprehension: `return [rule[i](args[i])) for i in xrange(len(rule))]`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether you are using Python 2.6 or 2.7, you could use the built in optparse or argparse, respectively.

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

They may be slightly heavyweight, but they'll do conversion to ints,floats, or whatever type you need as part of the parsing, and it can automatically build a usage message and other nice argument parsing things.

Comment: Looks like that idea would work, although a bit heavyweight as you pointed out. Thanks for the pointer. I'm accepting TokenMacGuy's solution as it's a bit slimmer.